# Flow map(Travel Path) Using Lat and Long in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, leaflet, gis, r-leaflet

I am trying to plot flow map (for singapore) . I have Entry(Lat,Long) and Exit (Lat,long). I am trying to map the flow from entry to exit in singapore map.

```
structure(list(token_id = c(1.12374e+19, 1.12374e+19, 1.81313e+19, 
1.85075e+19, 1.30752e+19, 1.30752e+19, 1.32828e+19, 1.70088e+19, 
1.70088e+19, 1.70088e+19, 1.05536e+19, 1.44818e+19, 1.44736e+19, 
1.44736e+19, 1.44736e+19, 1.44736e+19, 1.89909e+19, 1.15795e+19, 
1.15795e+19, 1.15795e+19, 1.70234e+19, 1.70234e+19, 1.44062e+19, 
1.21512e+19, 1.21512e+19, 1.95909e+19, 1.95909e+19, 1.50179e+19, 
1.50179e+19, 1.24174e+19, 1.36445e+19, 1.98549e+19, 1.92068e+19, 
1.18468e+19, 1.18468e+19, 1.92409e+19, 1.92409e+19, 1.21387e+19, 
1.9162e+19, 1.9162e+19, 1.40385e+19, 1.40385e+19, 1.32996e+19, 
1.32996e+19, 1.69103e+19, 1.69103e+19, 1.57387e+19, 1.40552e+19, 
1.40552e+19, 1.00302e+19), Entry_Station_Lat = c(1.31509, 1.33261, 
1.28425, 1.31812, 1.33858, 1.29287, 1.39692, 1.37773, 1.33858, 
1.33322, 1.28179, 1.30036, 1.43697, 1.39752, 1.27637, 1.39752, 
1.41747, 1.35733, 1.28405, 1.37773, 1.35898, 1.42948, 1.32774, 
1.42948, 1.349, 1.36017, 1.34971, 1.38451, 1.31509, 1.31509, 
1.37002, 1.34971, 1.31231, 1.39169, 1.31812, 1.44909, 1.29341, 
1.41747, 1.33759, 1.44062, 1.31509, 1.38451, 1.29461, 1.32388, 
1.41747, 1.27614, 1.39752, 1.39449, 1.33261, 1.31231), Entry_Station_Long = c(103.76525, 
103.84718, 103.84329, 103.89308, 103.70611, 103.8526, 103.90902, 
103.76339, 103.70611, 103.74217, 103.859, 103.85563, 103.7865, 
103.74745, 103.84596, 103.74745, 103.83298, 103.9884, 103.85152, 
103.76339, 103.75191, 103.83505, 103.67828, 103.83505, 103.74956, 
103.88504, 103.87326, 103.74437, 103.76525, 103.76525, 103.84955, 
103.87326, 103.83793, 103.89548, 103.89308, 103.82004, 103.78479, 
103.83298, 103.69742, 103.80098, 103.76525, 103.74437, 103.80605, 
103.93002, 103.83298, 103.79156, 103.74745, 103.90051, 103.84718, 
103.83793), Exit_Station_Lat = structure(c(48L, 34L, 118L, 60L, 
14L, 54L, 10L, 49L, 49L, 74L, 71L, 65L, 102L, 5L, 102L, 119L, 
116L, 10L, 13L, 88L, 117L, 66L, 40L, 62L, 117L, 37L, 67L, 34L, 
85L, 44L, 102L, 44L, 115L, 29L, 92L, 17L, 121L, 70L, 120L, 52L, 
85L, 34L, 42L, 11L, 4L, 115L, 62L, 48L, 92L, 14L), .Label = c("1.27082", 
"1.27091", "1.27236", "1.27614", "1.27637", "1.27646", "1.27935", 
"1.28221", "1.28247", "1.28405", "1.28621", "1.28819", "1.28932", 
"1.29287", "1.29309", "1.29338", "1.29341", "1.29461", "1.29694", 
"1.29959", "1.29974", "1.30034", "1.30252", "1.30287", "1.30392", 
"1.30394", "1.30619", "1.30736", "1.30842", "1.31139", "1.3115", 
"1.31167", "1.31188", "1.31509", "1.31654", "1.31756", "1.31913", 
"1.31977", "1.32008", "1.3205", "1.32104", "1.32388", "1.32573", 
"1.32725", "1.32774", "1.33119", "1.33155", "1.33261", "1.33322", 
"1.33474", "1.33554", "1.33759", "1.33764", "1.33858", "1.33921", 
"1.34037", "1.34225", "1.34293", "1.3432", "1.34426", "1.34857", 
"1.349", "1.34905", "1.35158", "1.35733", "1.35898", "1.36017", 
"1.3625", "1.36849", "1.37002", "1.37121", "1.37304", "1.37666", 
"1.37775", "1.3786", "1.37862", "1.38001", "1.38029", "1.3803", 
"1.38178", "1.38269", "1.38295", "1.38399", "1.38423", "1.38451", 
"1.38671", "1.38672", "1.38777", "1.38814", "1.3894", "1.39147", 
"1.39169", "1.39189", "1.39208", "1.39389", "1.39449", "1.39452", 
"1.39628", "1.39692", "1.39717", "1.39732", "1.39752", "1.39821", 
"1.39928", "1.39962", "1.4023", "1.40455", "1.40511", "1.40524", 
"1.40843", "1.40961", "1.41184", "1.41588", "1.41685", "1.41747", 
"1.42526", "1.42948", "1.43256", "1.43697", "1.44062", "1.44909"
), class = "factor"), Exit_Station_Long = structure(c(59L, 19L, 
27L, 4L, 65L, 3L, 63L, 6L, 6L, 21L, 93L, 121L, 9L, 56L, 9L, 32L, 
16L, 63L, 44L, 23L, 50L, 12L, 54L, 11L, 50L, 71L, 87L, 19L, 7L, 
118L, 9L, 118L, 49L, 90L, 96L, 31L, 45L, 61L, 38L, 2L, 7L, 19L, 
117L, 47L, 34L, 49L, 11L, 59L, 96L, 65L), .Label = c("103.67828", 
"103.69742", "103.70611", "103.72092", "103.73274", "103.74217", 
"103.74437", "103.74529", "103.74745", "103.74905", "103.74956", 
"103.75191", "103.7537", "103.75803", "103.76011", "103.76215", 
"103.76237", "103.76449", "103.76525", "103.76648", "103.76667", 
"103.76893", "103.7696", "103.77082", "103.77145", "103.77266", 
"103.774", "103.77866", "103.78185", "103.78425", "103.78479", 
"103.7865", "103.78744", "103.79156", "103.79631", "103.79654", 
"103.79836", "103.80098", "103.803", "103.80605", "103.80745", 
"103.80781", "103.80978", "103.81703", "103.82004", "103.82592", 
"103.82695", "103.83216", "103.83298", "103.83505", "103.83918", 
"103.83953", "103.83974", "103.84387", "103.84496", "103.84596", 
"103.84673", "103.84674", "103.84718", "103.84823", "103.84955", 
"103.85092", "103.85152", "103.85226", "103.8526", "103.85267", 
"103.85436", "103.85446", "103.85452", "103.86088", "103.86149", 
"103.86275", "103.86291", "103.86395", "103.86405", "103.86896", 
"103.87087", "103.87135", "103.87534", "103.87563", "103.8763", 
"103.87971", "103.88003", "103.88126", "103.88243", "103.88296", 
"103.88504", "103.8858", "103.88816", "103.8886", "103.88934", 
"103.89054", "103.89237", "103.89313", "103.8938", "103.89548", 
"103.89719", "103.89723", "103.89854", "103.9003", "103.90051", 
"103.90208", "103.90214", "103.9031", "103.90484", "103.90537", 
"103.90597", "103.90599", "103.90663", "103.9086", "103.90902", 
"103.9126", "103.9127", "103.91296", "103.91616", "103.9165", 
"103.93002", "103.94638", "103.94929", "103.95337", "103.9884"
), class = "factor")), .Names = c("token_id", "Entry_Station_Lat", 
"Entry_Station_Long", "Exit_Station_Lat", "Exit_Station_Long"
), row.names = c(10807L, 10808L, 10810L, 10815L, 10817L, 10818L, 
10819L, 10820L, 10823L, 10824L, 10826L, 10827L, 10829L, 10831L, 
10832L, 10833L, 10834L, 10835L, 10836L, 10838L, 10840L, 10841L, 
10843L, 10847L, 10850L, 10852L, 10854L, 10855L, 10859L, 10861L, 
10869L, 10872L, 10883L, 10886L, 10891L, 10895L, 10896L, 10897L, 
10900L, 10902L, 10903L, 10906L, 10910L, 10911L, 10912L, 10913L, 
10915L, 10920L, 10921L, 10924L), class = "data.frame")
```

I am trying to get something this : [Map Flow](http://flowingdata.com/2011/05/11/how-to-map-connections-with-great-circles/)

Comment: So, what is your problem ?There is no question here...

Comment: Is `token_id`the grouping variable?

Comment: Yes , token id is grouping variable

Comment: If I understand correctly you have different users who, e.g., bought a day ticket and took multiple rides. Are the rides already ordered in the original data set. My code assumes that.

Comment: Yes, they use same card to commute daily. This is a subset. The dataset is not ordered. But i have a date variable. I would generally like to see the pattern in which they travel. And figure most congested route

Comment: Well then I assume my plot should help you - you could include alpha in the geom_path to spot often overlayed paths as congested ones. To ensure validity of the individual user ride chains it is important to have the data sorted by ascending time. Your source had rounded paths but that is only helpful for long distance travel - on a city level I would recommend direct paths. Very interesting data!

Comment: I updated the solution to include curved lines between the stations. Feel free to indicate what prevents you from accepting any of the solutions.

Comment: @CMichael I am looking for something visually appealing (using Geospheres). Will wait for sometime, if nothing of that sort, will select an answer.

Comment: I would recommend updating your question to reflect this appropriately. So far you are asking - "I am trying to plot flow map (for singapore) ." It is a bit hard for contributors to guess what you are after in the end.

Comment: Had indicated a link to flowingdata in my question.

Comment: But the example were intercontinental connetions. Do you just want to include this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11813299/how-to-add-geo-spatial-connections-on-a-ggplot-map?

Comment: Most oft them in SO were intercontinental, so was looking something with geospheres and leaflets for a particular region (singapore)

Comment: I added an answer according to these request but you will be disappointed because the greactcircles are not bend because the distance within Singapore is too short.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alternative answer using `leaflet` and `geosphere`

```
#get Packages
require(leaflet)
require(geosphere)

#format data
a$Entry_Station_Long = as.numeric(as.character(a$Entry_Station_Long))
a$Entry_Station_Lat = as.numeric(as.character(a$Entry_Station_Lat))
a$Exit_Station_Long = as.numeric(as.character(a$Exit_Station_Long))
a$Exit_Station_Lat = as.numeric(as.character(a$Exit_Station_Lat))
a$id = as.factor(as.numeric(as.factor(a$token_id)))

#create some colors
factpal <- colorFactor(heat.colors(30), pathList$id)

#create a list of interpolated paths
pathList = NULL
for(i in 1:nrow(a))
{
tmp = gcIntermediate(c(a$Entry_Station_Long[i],
                 a$Entry_Station_Lat[i]),
               c(a$Exit_Station_Long[i],
                 a$Exit_Station_Lat[i]),n = 25,
               addStartEnd=TRUE)
tmp = data.frame(tmp)
tmp$id = a[i,]$id
tmp$color = factpal(a[i,]$id)
pathList = c(pathList,list(tmp))
}

#create empty base leaflet object
leaflet() %>% addTiles() -> lf

#add each entry of pathlist to the leaflet object
for (path in pathList)
{
  lf %>% addPolylines(data = path,
                      lng = ~lon, 
                      lat = ~lat,
                      color = ~color) -> lf

}
#show output
lf
```

Note that as I mentioned before there is no way of geosphering the paths in such a small locality - the great circles are effectively straight lines. If you want the rounded edges for sake of aesthetics you may have to use the geom_curve way described in my other answer.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Just realized that the original solution usin `geom_path` was more complicated than necessary. `geom_segment`works without changing the data:

```
require(ggplot2)
require(ggmap)
basemap <- get_map("Singapore",
                   source = "stamen",
                   maptype = "toner",
                   zoom = 11)

g = ggplot(a)
map = ggmap(basemap, base_layer = g)
map = map + coord_cartesian() +
      geom_curve(size = 1.3,
                 aes(x=as.numeric(Entry_Station_Long),
                     y=as.numeric(Entry_Station_Lat),
                     xend=as.numeric(as.character(Exit_Station_Long)),
                     yend=as.numeric(as.character(Exit_Station_Lat)),
                     color=as.factor(token_id)))
map
```

This solution leverages [Draw curved lines in ggmap, geom_curve not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36501227/draw-curved-lines-in-ggmap-geom-curve-not-working) to implement curved lines on a map.

`ggmaps` used for simplicity - for more ambitious projects I would recommend `leaflet`.

[image]

Below the solution using a long data format with some prior data wrangling. It also uses straight lines instead of the curves above.

```
a %>%
  mutate(path = row_number()) -> a

origin = select(a,token_id,Entry_Station_Lat,Entry_Station_Long,path)
origin$type = "origin"
dest = select(a,token_id,Exit_Station_Lat,Exit_Station_Long,path)
dest$type = "dest"

colnames(origin) = c("id","lat","long","path","type")
colnames(dest) = c("id","lat","long","path","type")
complete = rbind(origin,dest)
complete %>% arrange(path,type) -> complete

require(ggmap)
basemap <- get_map("Singapore",
                   source = "stamen",
                   maptype = "toner",
                   zoom = 11)

g = ggplot(complete, aes(x=as.numeric(long),
                         y=as.numeric(lat)))
map = ggmap(basemap, base_layer = g)

map + geom_path(aes(color = as.factor(id)),
                size = 1.1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, i am looking for a leaflet approach. nevertheless its a great start and learning for me.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to plot it on an actual Google Map, and recreate the style of your linked map, you can use my `googleway` package that uses Google's Maps API. You need an API key to use their maps

```
library(googleway)

df$Exit_Station_Lat <- as.numeric(as.character(df$Exit_Station_Lat))
df$Exit_Station_Long <- as.numeric(as.character(df$Exit_Station_Long))

df$polyline <- apply(df, 1, function(x) {
    lat <- c(x['Entry_Station_Lat'], x['Exit_Station_Lat'])
    lon <- c(x['Entry_Station_Long'], x['Exit_Station_Long'])
    encode_pl(lat = lat, lon = lon)
})

mapKey <- 'your_api_key'

style <- '[ { "stylers": [{ "visibility": "simplified"}]},{"stylers": [{"color": "#131314"}]},{"featureType": "water","stylers": [{"color": "#131313"},{"lightness": 7}]},{"elementType": "labels.text.fill","stylers": [{"visibility": "on"},{"lightness": 25}]}]'

google_map(key = mapKey, style = style) %>%
    add_polylines(data = df, 
      polyline = "polyline", 
      mouse_over_group = "Entry_Station_Lat",
      stroke_weight = 0.7,  
      stroke_opacity = 0.5, 
      stroke_colour = "#ccffff")
```

[image]

---

Note, to recreate the map using flight data, see the example given in `?add_polylines`

---

You can also show other types of routes, for example, driving between the locations by using Google's Directions API to encode the driving routes.

```
df$drivingRoute <- lst_directions <- apply(df, 1, function(x){
    orig <- as.numeric(c(x['Entry_Station_Lat'], x['Entry_Station_Long']))
    dest <- as.numeric(c(x['Exit_Station_Lat'], x['Exit_Station_Long']))

    dir <- google_directions(origin = orig, destination = dest, key = apiKey)
    dir$routes$overview_polyline$points
})


google_map(key = mapKey, style = style) %>%
    add_polylines(data = df, 
      polyline = "drivingRoute", 
      mouse_over_group = "Entry_Station_Lat",
      stroke_weight = 0.7,  
      stroke_opacity = 0.5, 
      stroke_colour = "#ccffff")
```

[image]

Comment: This looks good. I need my visulaization to look something (where Entry and Exit should indicate as a Point and the lines should be curved. More Visually appealing.)

Answer (score 5):

I've also written the [`mapdeck`](https://github.com/SymbolixAU/mapdeck) library to make visualisations like this more appealing*

```
library(mapdeck)

set_token("MAPBOX_TOKEN")  ## set your mapbox token here

df$Exit_Station_Lat <- as.numeric(as.character(df$Exit_Station_Lat))
df$Exit_Station_Long <- as.numeric(as.character(df$Exit_Station_Long))

mapdeck(
  style = mapdeck_style('dark')
  , location = c(104, 1)
  , zoom = 8
  , pitch = 45
) %>%
  add_arc(
    data = df
    , origin = c("Entry_Station_Long", "Entry_Station_Lat")
    , destination = c("Exit_Station_Long", "Exit_Station_Lat")
    , layer_id = 'arcs'
    , stroke_from_opacity = 100
    , stroke_to_opacity = 100
    , stroke_width = 3
    , stroke_from = "#ccffff"
    , stroke_to = "#ccffff"
  )
```

[image]

*subjectively speaking

Comment: really nice job

Answer (score 1):

I would like to leave an alternative approach for you. What you can do is to restructure your data. Right now you have two columns for entry stations and the other two for exit stations. You can create one column for long, and another for lat by combing these columns. The trick is to use `rbind()` and `c()`.

Let's have a look of this simple example.

```
x <- c(1, 3, 5)
y <- c(2, 4, 6)
c(rbind(x, y))

#[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

Imagine x is long for entry stations and y for exit stations. 1 is longitude for a starting point. 2 is longitude where the first journey ended. As far as I can see from your sample data, it seems that 3 is identical 2. You could remove duplicated data points for each token_id. If you have a large set of data, perhaps this is something you want to consider. Back to the main point, you can create a column with longitude in the sequence you want with the combination of the two functions. Since you said you have date information, make sure you order the data by date. Then, the sequence of each journey appears in the right way in `tmp`. You want to do this with latitude as well.

Now we look into your sample data. It seems that `Exit_Station_Lat` and `Exit_Station_Long` are in factor. The first operation is to convert them to numeric. Then, you apply the method above and create a data frame. I called your data `mydf`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggalt)
library(ggthemes)
library(raster)

mydf %>%
mutate_at(vars(Exit_Station_Lat: Exit_Station_Long),
          funs(as.numeric(as.character(.)))) -> mydf

group_by(mydf, token_id) %>%
do(data.frame(long = c(rbind(.$Entry_Station_Long,.$Exit_Station_Long)),
              lat = c(rbind(.$Entry_Station_Lat, .$Exit_Station_Lat))
             )
   ) -> tmp
```

Now let's get a map data from GADM. You can download data using the `raster` package.

```
getData(name = "GADM", country = "singapore", level = 0) %>%
fortify -> singapore
```

Finally, you draw a map. The key thing is to use `group` in `aes` in `geom_path()`. I hope this will let you move forward.

```
ggplot() +
geom_cartogram(data = singapore,
               aes(x = long, y = lat, map_id = id),
               map = singapore) +
geom_path(data = tmp,
          aes(x = long, y = lat, group = token_id,
          color = as.character(token_id)),
          show.legend = FALSE) +
theme_map()
```

[image]

Comment: Clear. Any approach with leaflet.

Comment: @RUser Have a look of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32275213/how-do-i-connect-two-coordinates-with-a-line-using-leaflet-in-r/32281435#32281435)

Comment: Thanks, will have a look.